# How to convert a byte stream from a POST request to an image?

Tags: byte, bytecode, mitmproxy

I am using mitmproxy to sniff out a POST request that sends an image. However, the image seems to be sent as bytes, and I cannot figure out how to convert those bytes back to an image.

Already tried:
Copying and pasting the bytes to a file via notepad++
Using hexedit to create a new file with these bytes
Use an online hex to image converter

All of the above methods tell me the file is corrupted.

Part of stream:

START

```
\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00H\x00H\x00\x00\xff\xe1\x07\x88Exif\x00\x00MM\x00*\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00   \x01\x0f\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00z\x01\x10\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00   \x00\x00\x00\x80\x01\x12\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x01\x1a\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x8a\x01\x1b\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x92\x01(\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x011\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x9a\x012\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x87i\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb4\x00\x00\x00\x00Apple\x00iPhone 7\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00H\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00H\x00\x00\x00\x0113.3\x00\x002022:05:22 20:33:01\x00\x00$\x82\x9a\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02j\x82\x9d\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02r\x88"\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x88'\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x90\x00\x00\x90\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x040231\x90\x03\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x02z\x90\x04\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x02\x8e\x90\x10\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x02\xa2\x90\x11\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x02\xaa\x90\x12\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x02\xb2\x91\x01\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x04\x01\x02\x03\x00\x92\x01\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02\xba\x92\x02\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02\xc2\x92\x03\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02\xca\x92\x04\x00
```

END:

```
\x18\xb2\x12\x04\x8f\xd3\xb50.%\xaa\xa22K\xf3`\xf1\xfe5LHX\x90;;JN\xc8\x95\xbe\xef\x04\x90{\x9a\x82\x99*\xc9\x85b@ \x0c\x81Mnb\xc7\xb7\x9c\xdf\xbb\x0f\x90y9\xef\xedC\x924Mu/\xad\xb4ko\xb0\xe4\xefm\xb8\xf4\xc7\xa1\xa6\x99\x99\x08\xde\xd9F\xc7\xc8s\xf8-U\xc6M\x04\xca\xc3\xe5\\s\xcf=y\xc5R\xb8\x1a\xd6\xf6\xaa \xf2\xf8i\x1b\xbf8\xab\x00\x8c\x86Uw\xce{\xe0\xfb\xe2\xb3RD\x12d\xc6\xbed\x84\xb8\x07\xa7\xbf\xadY\xa2,0\x89|\xb6\x95|\xc0\xfc\xe4\xf5\xf6\xac\xc2\xf6  Z\x18cT(w1\x010x\x1b\xbaf\x81^\xe5\xa8\xad\x01\x901b\xaf\x1f\x18\x1fw\x8fJ  \xd4\x8a#\xba\x0f=\xd0\x12\xc0\xb7^\xfe\x99\xa0Vf\x8f\x95!\x825b\xa3\x1b\x8bapX\x0e\xd9\xad\x00\x86\x063<|\x90\x1b\x81\xcfLT2\xedm\x0bW\x08N\xe8\x83\x10\xc4\xf1\xc7\x18\xadX\x91V\xee5\xb7\x80(;\x99\xdba8\xfdj4(\xff\xd9
```

The image is an jpg, and the bytes seem to match JPG standard (Starting with xff, ending with xd9.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, got it working:

I found this link:
https://laurentmeyer.medium.com/understanding-jpeg-format-the-hard-way-57dd34abe2f1

Checked the HEX data of my request, copied the hex codes between xffxd8 and xffxd9, then used a tool on codepen to convert it back into an image.

To convert it back to an image, that worked.